# select two columns based on the maximum value of the other column in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

Hi this is the table Im using say Loandetails

```
Loanno  Balance amount  DueDATE
1001045 308731.770000   12/31/99
1001045 2007700.740000  12/31/99
1001045 3087318905.770000   11/01/99
1001045 308731.770000   12/31/99
```

I have to select `Loanno` and `DueDate` based on the `maximum value of Balance Amount`.
`Loanno` is not unique.Please help me out on this.

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT L.Loanno, L.Balanceamount, L.DueDate
     FROM dbo.Loan L 
     INNER JOIN 
         (
          SELECT Loanno, MAX(Balancemount) as MaxBalance FROM dbo.Loan
             GROUP BY LoanNo
         ) SUB ON L.Loanno = SUB.Loanno AND L.Balanceamount = SUB.MaxBalance
```

The sub query returns the `Maximum balance` for each LoanNo (regardless of date)
When joined back to your original table you are left with the LoanNo, Maximum Balance and Date at which this is Due.

Ok just tested the query below in MS Acccess and it works just fine, substitute `Table1` with your actual table name:

```
SELECT T.LoanNo, T.DueDate, T.BalanceAmount
 FROM Table1 As T
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT T.Loanno, Max([T.Balanceamount]) AS MaxBalance
     FROM Table1 as T
     GROUP BY T.Loanno) SUB ON T.LoanNo = SUB.LoanNo AND T.BalanceAmount = SUB.MaxBalance
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) ranking function

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Loanno ORDER BY [Balance Amount] DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.your_tableName
  )
  SELECT Loanno, DueDate
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work, a subquery pulling back the max value of the Balance field that is then used to find the one (or more) records with the same value.

```
select LoanNo, DueDate 
from _LoanData 
where Balance = (
    select max(Balance)
    from _loandata
    )
```

or this, which pulls the top 1 (first record) from a list that's ordered by the balance in descending order. Performance wise, this is slower.

```
select top 1 LoanNo, DueDate, Balance
from _LoanData 
order by Balance desc
```

Good luck.

Comment: This works only if I have 1 Loan number...What if If I have multiple loan numbers?

Comment: Brian, although the sample dataset doesn't illustrate it I would imply there could be different loanno records in the same table, your queries don't work when this is the case as they only cater for the loan with the highest Balance overall not by Loan.

Comment: Select top 1 LoanNo, DueDate, balance
from _LoanData 
order by balance desc, duedate desc ... this will return the max balance with the highest (max) DueDate

Answer (score -1):

Try this out -:

```
SELECT Loanno ,DueDate 
FROM
     (SELECT Loanno ,DueDate , MAX(Balance amount) BAL_AMT
      FROM Loandetails 
      GROUP BY Loanno ,DueDate 
     )
```

Comment: Grouping by Loanno and DueDate doesn't help find the Date at which the maximum balance is due, it just finds the maximum balance for a unique date.

Comment: Yes you are correct CSL. I misread the question. It should have been maximum balance amount by Loanno.